# How $44:9.3 = 5.5:1.16 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is actually mentioned in my module,I am not sure how they have got this result but I think this may not be correct,I tried using [wolfarm alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=44%2F9.3%20%3D%3D%205.5%2F1.16&t=ff3tb01) which gives false or am I missing something?

---

I was missing approximation,it seems like data interpretation problems keeps relying on this, so,$$\frac{44}{9.3} = 4.73118 \text{ and } \frac{5.5}{1.16} =  4.74138 $$ Hence, $44:9.3 \approx 5.5:1.16$

Comment: What do you even mean by that implication?

Comment: Jasper, thanks I figured it out, if you post that comment as your answer, I will rather be happy in accepting  it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eyeballed it this way:

$$\frac {44} {9.3} = \frac {11} {2.325}$$

while:

$$\frac {5.5} {1.16} = \frac {11} {2.32}$$

So one expects roughly three significant figures of agreement but not equality.

Answer (score 0):

A quick computation gives that
$$ \begin{align}
{440 \over 93} = {550 \over 116} 
  &\iff {440 \times 116 \over 93 \times 116} = {550 \times 93 \over 116 \times 93} \\\\
  &\iff 440 \times 116 = 550 \times 93 \\\\
  &\iff 44 \times 116 = 55 \times 93,
\end{align} $$
and in the last equality the LHS is even and RHS is odd, so they can't possibly be equal.

Comment: Yes, they are  not equal but as Jasper mentioned I too believe that this is a kind of approximation but am not able to find out (yet) how this approximation could be done,manually of-course.

Comment: Then maybe you should edit the question so it asks how one might 'guess' that $44:9.3 \approx 5.5:1.16$ rather than "How $44:9.3 = 5.5:1.16$"?

Comment: Okay I figured it out $\frac{44}{9.3} = 4.73118$ and $\frac{5.5}{1.16} =  4.74138$. Hence the approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the approximation arises from solving $\rm\displaystyle\ \frac{44}{x} = \frac{5.5}{1.16}\ \Rightarrow\;\ x = \frac{1.16\cdot 44}{5.5} = 9.28 \approx 9.3$